# Control-Alt-Delete from python or command line

Tags: python, command-line, wxpython

I've done some research but I would like to be able to call control-alt-delete from python. If that is not possible is it possible to call it from command line because then I could just use that command in python because I can call command lines in python. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. this is for a task manager written with wxPython. 
edit:
im trying to launch the windows security and from a user answer i tried

```
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys("{CONTROL}{ALT}{DELETE}")
```

and i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Python27/tescontrol.py", line 4, in <module>
      shell.SendKeys("{CONTROL}{ALT}{DELETE}")
    File "<COMObject WScript.Shell>", line 2, in SendKeys
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: which operating systems?

Comment: According to this article, it's not possible and would be considered a Windows bug as far as accessing the command from Python. Apparently, ctrl+alt+del is a secure set of keystrokes and can only be responded to from the OS: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/940378, not sure about the command prompt, a basic Google search didn't put up anything promising.

Comment: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/10/03/how-to-find-and-list-all-running-processes-with-python/  ... may lead towards your goal state

Comment: my operating system is windows and im trying to launch the security screen because i like the options and i dont think you can change a users password from python its a feature i would use that is why i want to inplant it

Answer (score 1):

You surely mean activating the Windows Security window.  In this case:

```
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys("^(%{DELETE})")
```

UPDATE

The above code seems not to work because of the reasons described in other posts.  In that case, the alternative is to create a similar window and call from Python the different programs/functions called by the real Windows Security window.

On reading OP's comments to the original question, OP's final need is to change a user's password.  This can be done with:

```
from win32com import adsi
ads_obj = adsi.ADsGetObject("WinNT://localhost/%s,user" % username)
ads_obj.SetPassword(password)
```

I just tested this in my PC, so is final information (though not necessarily *correct*; this is up to the OP :-) ).

UPDATE 2:  Copying the later as a separate answer as comments seem to indicate that all of the answer doesn't work.  This is correct for the `SendKeys` proposition, which doesn't work.

Comment: It shouldn't work for alt-ctl-delete which is handled specially in the bios/os.

Comment: doesnt work on windows 8 i updated the question with the error

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to shutdown or restart the system, Windows has a 'shutdown' command and linux's typically have 'shutdown' and 'reboot' commands.

Comment: afaik thats not what he wants ... but if it is you can use win32api also .... but this should have been a comment really .

Comment: We can't downvote an answer because its author fails in guessing correctly a horribly badly terribly worded question. +1 (to make it at least 0)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following thread:

- http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?330557-Ctrl-alt-delete

According to it, VNC uses something like this:

```
PostMessage HWND_BROADCAST, WM_HOTKEY, 0, MakeLong(MOD_ALT Or MOD_CONTROL, VK_DELETE)
```

I suspect you would need to use ctypes or PyWin32 to do something like this. I would probably go with ctypes since it's cross-platform, however, even with ctypes you would probably need to write a special method for each OS that you support.

Comment: No, it's not. You would have to look at VNC's code and then port it to Python. That looks like stuff I've seen in PyWin32, but I know you can use ctypes for this sort of thing as well.

Comment: i'm about two months into python so i would have no idea how to do that

Comment: Use Google - for example, I googled for ctypes HWND_BROADCAST and got this link: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577233-adding-the-directory-of-the-python-executable-to-t/history/1/

Answer (score 0):

On reading OP's comments, his/her original need was to change the user's password.  In fact, this can be done with:

```
from win32com import adsi
ads_obj = adsi.ADsGetObject("WinNT://localhost/%s,user" % username)
ads_obj.SetPassword(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vncdotool library
At:

> [lib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vncdotool/0.1.1)

And use vncdotool by:

```
os.system("vncdotool key ctrl-alt-del")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can try at least:
(It may only work on windows 7)

```
import sys
import localize
import os
value_from = 0
Integer = _clear_type_cache(get_object[win\%sys(vnc_value*cache)* value_from])

def Interclass(event): 
    try:
      [<'ctrl'><'alt'><'del'>{%user_value(*object)*value_form}] % cache
    except: 
     {%TOPMOST%'TEMP'_%VALUE_REGISTRY}*
    else: 
    print("No value")
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, Ctrl-Alt-Delete is protected for security reasons, so programs cannot use it. (At least in Windows 7 and before.)

Comment: You cannot block it but you can simulate it